# GPUImage index out of bounds crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

I have a camera app on the app store that uses GPUImage to take pictures and record videos. I am getting crash reports that says its crashing for a lot of users with the error

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
*** -[NSArray| objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

The crash report says the crash occurs in the **GPUImageStillCamera.m** class at **line 283**. Below is the crash report. I appreciate your help in advance.

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 6484558552 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                6783221988 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 6483393332 CFRunLoopRemoveTimer
3  Selfie                         4297468448 -[GPUImageStillCamera capturePhotoProcessedUpToFilter:withImageOnGPUHandler:] (GPUImageStillCamera.m:283)
4  Selfie                         4297465636 -[GPUImageStillCamera capturePhotoAsImageProcessedUpToFilter:withOrientation:withCompletionHandler:] (GPUImageStillCamera.m:171)
5  Selfie                         4295826452 +[SEMediaCapture captureImageFromCamera:withFilter:completion:] (SEMediaCapture.m:39)
6  Selfie                         4296216108 -[SEViewController takePicture] (SEViewController.m:595)
7  Selfie                         4296201380 -[SEViewController tappedToTakeAPicture:] (SEViewController.m:216)
8  UIKit                          6564311152 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions
9  UIKit                          6562842292 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:]
10 UIKit                          6567498636 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke662
11 UIKit                          6562595864 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks
12 UIKit                          6562588612 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate
13 UIKit                          6562834476 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:]
14 UIKit                          6562832100 -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
15 UIKit                          6562648352 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
16 UIKit                          6565405368 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent
17 UIKit                          6562641460 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue
18 CoreFoundation                 6484263488 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
19 CoreFoundation                 6484260068 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
20 CoreFoundation                 6484252052 __CFRunLoopRun
21 CoreFoundation                 6483382996 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
22 GraphicsServices               6645217020 GSEventRunModal
23 UIKit                          6563065664 UIApplicationMain
24 Selfie                         4296168708 main (main.m:15)
25 libdyld.dylib                  6790212104 start
```